# Does anyone know what these comments by my teacher mean? Im not sure how to do that

Tags: java

The part that I don't know how to do starts at the scramble button method where there are about 5 comments and I have code underneath them. I am relatively new to coding and I can say I'm not very good at it so any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure what 'remembering' means in this context nor do I have any idea what to do.

````
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random.*;

public class SliderGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

  private JButton[] button = new JButton[16];

  public SliderGame() {
    setSize(340, 410);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // allow frame window to close
    setLayout(null); // allows to describe the location and size of anything you add to the frame.

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    Font buttonFont = new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 20);

    int x = 10;
    int y = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
      final int final_i = i;
      button[i] = new JButton();
      button[i].addActionListener(this);
      button[i].setBounds(x, y, 75, 75); // (right, down, width, height)
      button[i].setText(i + " ");
      button[i].setFont(buttonFont);
      c.add(button[i]);
      x = x + 80;

      if (x > 250) {
        y = y + 80;
        x = 10;
      } // end if
    } // end for

    button[0].setVisible(false);

    JButton playButton = new JButton("Click to play!");
    playButton.addActionListener(this);
    playButton.setBounds(100, 335, 130, 40);
    playButton.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
    Font playFont = new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 12);
    playButton.setFont(playFont);
    c.add(playButton);

    setVisible(true); // allows us to see everything that we add to the frame.
  } // end constructor method

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == button[0]){
      System.out.println("button 0 was pressed!");
    } // end if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[1]){
      System.out.println("1st button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[2]){
      System.out.println("2nd button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[3]){
      System.out.println("3rd button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[4]){
      System.out.println("4th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[5]){
      System.out.println("5th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[6]){
      System.out.println("6th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[7]){
      System.out.println("7th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[8]){
      System.out.println("8th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[9]){
      System.out.println("9th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[10]){
      System.out.println("10th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[11]){
      System.out.println("11th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[12]){
      System.out.println("12th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[13]){
      System.out.println("13th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[14]){
      System.out.println("14th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if

    else if(e.getSource() == button[15]){
      System.out.println("15th button was pressed!");
    } // end else if
  } // end actionPerformed method

  public void scrambleButtons() {
    // let's ignore the first (blank) button and keep it right where it is!

    // 1. generate a random number from 1 to 15: randomIndex1
    double random = Math.random();
    random *= 15;
    int randomIndex1 = (int)random;

    // 2. generate a random number from 1 to 15: randomIndex2
    double random2 = Math.random();
    random2 *= 15;
    int randomIndex2 = (int)random;

    // 3. now take the text from the butoon at randomIndex1 and remember it: str1
    int str1 = button[randomIndex1];
    
    // 4. now take the text from the butoon at randomIndex2 and remember it: str2
    int str2 = button[randomIndex2];

    // 5. using the strings you remembered in steps 3 and 4, set the text on the other button, for example:
    button[randomIndex1].setText(str2);

    // once you have those steps working put all of that code inside a for loop so that it can repeat at least 100 times
    
  } // end scrambleButtons method
} // end class ```
````

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz yes it is homework. I do know what a for loop is, I know how to use it but in this context I'm clueless.

Comment: There are a lot of comments in this piece of code, can you narrow it down to one specific comment that you don't understand?  As a side note, I don't like the way your teacher has done this with a null layout.  If they want a grid, they should use a grid layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For #2, `randomIndex2` should be assigned from `random2`, not from `random`.
- For #3 and #4, *"take the **text** from the button"* means to call `getText()` to get the `String` value with the text shown in the button.

  ```java
  String str1 = button[randomIndex1].getText();
  String str2 = button[randomIndex2].getText();
  ```
- For #5, *"set the text on the **other** button"* basically means that you will be swapping the text labels of the two buttons, e.g. if the random numbers are 3 and 7, then get the two text labels, and set them back, flipped.

  ```java
  button[randomIndex1].setText(str2);
  button[randomIndex2].setText(str1);
  ```
- For the last, just do exactly what it says, surround all the code of #1-#5 with a loop that repeats 100 times.

You have 16 buttons, so if you randomly swap 2 of them, and do that 100 times, you will essentially have shuffled (scrambled) the buttons.

It is a sub-optimal way to do it. There are better algorithms, but maybe that will be next weeks lesson.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot! :)